# Python (rospy) to C++ (roscpp) struct.unpack

Tags: python, c++, ros, code-translation

I am currently translating a rospy IMU-driver to roscpp and have difficulites figuring out what this piece of code does and how I can translate it.

```
def ReqConfiguration(self):
    """Ask for the current configuration of the MT device.
    Assume the device is in Config state."""
    try:
        masterID, period, skipfactor, _, _, _, date, time, num, deviceID,\
                length, mode, settings =\
                struct.unpack('!IHHHHI8s8s32x32xHIHHI8x', config)
    except struct.error:
        raise MTException("could not parse configuration.")
    conf = {'output-mode': mode,
            'output-settings': settings,
            'length': length,
            'period': period,
            'skipfactor': skipfactor,
            'Master device ID': masterID,
            'date': date,
            'time': time,
            'number of devices': num,
            'device ID': deviceID}
    return conf
```

I have to admit that I never ever worked with neither ros nor python before. 
This is no 1:1 code from the source, I removed the lines I think I know what they do, but especially the try-block is what I don't understand. I would really appreciate help, because I am under great preasure of time.

If someone is curious(context reasons): The files I have to translate are mtdevice.py , mtnode.py and mtdef.py and can be found googleing for the filesnames + the keyword ROS IMU Driver

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the same thing with C++, you'd declare a `struct` with the various parameters:

```
struct DeviceRecord {
    uint32_t masterId;
    uint16_t period, skipfactor, _a, _b;
    uint32_t _c;
    char date[8];
    char time[8];
    char padding[64];
    uint16_t num;
    uint32_t deviceID;
    uint16_t length, mode;
    uint32_t settings;
    char padding[8];
};
```

(It's possible this struct is already declared somewhere; it might also use "unsigned int" instead of "uint32_t" and "unsigned short" instead of "uint16_t", and _a, _b, _c would probably have real names.)

Once you have your struct, the question is how to get the data. That depends on where the data is. If it's in a file, you'd do something like this:

```
DeviceRecord rec; // An instance of the struct, whatever it's called
std::ifstream fin("yourfile.txt", std::ios::binary);
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&rec), sizeof(rec));
// Now you can access rec.masterID etc
```

On the other hand, if it's somewhere in memory (ie, you have a char* or void* to it), then you just need to cast it:

```
void* data_source = get_data(...); // You'd get this from somewhere
DeviceRecord* rec_ptr = reinterpret_cast<DeviceRecord*>(stat_source);
// Now you can access rec_ptr->masterID etc
```

If you have a `std::vector`, you can easily get such a pointer:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> data_source = get_data(...); // As above
DeviceRecord* rec_ptr = reinterpret_cast<DeviceRecord*>(data_source.data());
// Now you can access rec_ptr->masterID etc, provided data_source remains in scope. You should probably also avoid modifying data_source.
```

There's one more issue here. The data you've received is in big-endian, but unless you have a PowerPC or other unusual processor, you're probably on a little-endian machine. So you need to do a little byte-swapping before you access the data. You can use the following function to do this.

```
template<typename Int>
Int swap_int(Int n) {
    if(sizeof(Int) == 2) {
        union {char c[2]; Int i;} swapper;
        swapper.i = n;
        std::swap(swapper.c[0], swapper.c[1]);
        n = swapper.i;
    } else if(sizeof(Int) == 4) {
        union {char c[4]; Int i;} swapper;
        swapper.i = n;
        std::swap(swapper.c[0], swapper.c[3]);
        std::swap(swapper.c[1], swapper.c[2]);
        n = swapper.i;
    }
    return n;
}
```

These return the swapped value rather than changing it in-place, so now you'd access your data with something like `swap_int(rec->num)`. NB: The above byte-swapping code is untested; I'll try compiling it a bit later and fix it if necessary.

Without more information, I can't give you a definitive way of doing this, but perhaps this will be enough to help you work it out on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am confused. Wherefore are the parameters in the struct.unpack function? And how do I know which data it does access, it is just this line, and nowhere is any struct declared. I thought the string-parameter might be a packed version of the data? I mean, python does somehow need to know where it gets its data from, but there is no type specification nor any struct in the whole node...

Comment: No. The parameter, `'!IHHHHI8s8s32x32xHIHHI8x'`, specifies the _format_ of the data. It's the equivalent of the `struct` declaration in my post (I literally built that declaration based on the string parameter). (Note though that my post is missing an essential detail that slipped my mind, which I will edit in as soon as I can.) Anyway, the actual data is stored in the `config` variable in your code.

Comment: config is the return type of another function and an array of uint8_t 's. Still do not know what to do with this :( I have the format of the data and I have an vector of bytes.. now what :D

Comment: As in, `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` or similar?

Comment: std::vector<uint8_t>, yes

Comment: Alright, I updated the byte-swapping section and added a note on `vector`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have a similar code where the input data is a string. How would I reinterprete a string to a Struct?

Comment: for example
`mid, length = struct.unpack('!BB', self.device.read(2))
   if length==255: # extended length
    length, = struct.unpack('!H', self.device.read(2))`
Where is the difference in the struct.unpack? What does this "formation" mean to me, when I translate it? I have got the code to compile but wasn't able to test it yet, since I need the robot at the university to do so (tomorrow), but I do not see an option that represents the "formation" parameter

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you use `'!BB'` you'll get back two numbers (I'll call them A and B) between 0 and 255, while if you use `'!H'` you'll get back one number between 0 and 65535 (I'll call it C). Assuming the data (`self.device.read(2)`) is the same, you'll find that `C == A * 256 + B`.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code unpacks the fields of a C structure, namely  masterID, period, skipfactor, _, _, _, date, time, num, deviceID, length, mode, settings, stores those in a Python dictionary and returns that dictionary as call result. The underscores are placeholders for the parts of the struct that aren't used.

See also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html, e.g. for a description of the format string ('!IHHHHI8s8s32x32xHIHHI8x') that tells the unpack function what the struct looks like.

The syntax a, b, c, d = f () means that the function returns a thing called a tuple in Python. By assigning a tuple to multiple variables, it's split into its fields.

Example:

```
 t = (1, 2, 3, 4)

 a, b, c, d = t

 # At this point a == 1, b == 2, c == 3, d == 4
```

To replace this piece of code by C++ should not be too hard, since C++ has structs much like C. So the simplest C++ implementation of requestConfiguration would be to just return that struct. If you want to stay closer to the Python functionality, your function could put the fields of the struct into a C++ STL map and return that. The format string + the docs that the link points to, tell you what data types are in your struct and where.

Note that it's the second parameter of unpack that holds your data, the first parameter just contains information on the layout (format) of the second parameter, as explained in the link. The second parameter looks to Python as if it's a string, but it's actually a C struct. The first parameter tells Python where to find what in that struct.

So if you read the docs on format strings, you can find out the layout of your second parameter (C struct). But maybe you don't need to. It depends on the caller of your function. It may just expect the plain C struct.

From your added comments I understand that there's more code in your function than you show. The fields of the structs are assigned to attributes of a class.

If you know the field names of your C struct (config) then you can assign them directly to the attributes of your C++ class.

```
// Pointer 'this' isn't needed but inserted for clarity

this->mode = config.mode;
this->settings = config.settings;
this->length = config.length;
```

I've assumed that the field names of the config struct are indeed mode, settings, length etc. but you'd have to verify that. Probably the layout of this struct is declared in some C header file (or in the docs).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have an idea how I could translate it to c++? I now understand the part before the '=', but what exactly does struct.unpack do with its parameters. As far as my research brought me, I found out that the first parameter, the string, are bytes packed to a string. I do not know what would be neccessary to get the same data / results in c++

Comment: What I came up with is to convert the string to a char-array and iterate through this piece of code I found on the net. 


`int32_t bigEndianValue;
memcpy(&bigEndianValue, &myByteArray[0], sizeof(bigEndianValue));
int32_t theUnpackedValue = ntohl(bigEndianValue);`
`

where myByteArray is the first parameter of the struct.unpack function. Is that approach right?

Comment: Sounds complicated. It depends on what the caller of your function is expecting, maybe just a struct... Do you have doc's on the caller, I know nothing of ros, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not fluent in english so I am not sure If I did understand your question. Do you want to know "who" calls this function? If yes, I checked, and the return value is never used. But some class members are set from the resulting data from the struct.unpack 
`self.mode = mode
  self.settings = settings
  self.length = length
  self.header = '\xFA\xFF\x32'+chr(length)`